# Restlet API stops working when creating a .exe

Tags: java, restlet, restful-url, exe4j

I'm making a Java application which uses [Restlet](http://restlet.com/products/restlet-framework/) to create a restful API.
It works pretty well when running it from Eclipse but whenever I generate a .exe file (with [exe4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files) ) and I run it from there the restful API stops working showing a `Not found` error (10.4.5 404 Not Found)

Why is this happening?

I'm including all the needed libraries when creating the .exe as far as I know. This is my `.xml` file used in exe4j:

```
    <pathelement location="${lib}/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/jacob.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/joda-time-2.3.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/json-simple-1.1.1.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/junit-4.11.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/log4j-api-2.0.1.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/log4j-core-2.0.1.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/mail.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/ojdbc6.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/org.restlet.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/pdfbox-app-1.8.0.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/sigar.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/guava-17.0.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib}/zeromq.jar" />
```

- [Complete .xml file](http://paste.ofcode.org/7rd9Vm5R84iZrH5QVXmyhL)
- [Complete .exe4j file](http://paste.ofcode.org/gjMyEKHAxaigF6xVATkVcV)
- [Log shown in Eclipse when compiling the .exe with exe4j](http://paste.ofcode.org/NTrGCTKfAYcqEnk6F7Ybbw)

In case this is relevant at all, here's the way I create the routes:

```
   /* Creates a root Restlet that will receive all incoming calls.*/
   @Override
   public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
       // Create a router Restlet that routes each call to  the relevant instance
       Router router = new Router(getContext());

       // Defines routes
       router.attach("/users", UsersController.class);
       router.attach("/departments", DepartmentsController.class);
       router.attach("/absences", AbsencesController.class);

       router.attachDefault(RestDefault.class);

       return router;
   }
```

Comment: Anything in the logs of the embeeded http server ?

Comment: Probably you don't pack *your* resources into the .exe. The server cannot find (instatiate) them because the class isn't available.

Comment: @PeterMmm how can I check the logs? And, what do you mean with the packing? [This is my full `.xml` file](http://paste.ofcode.org/7rd9Vm5R84iZrH5QVXmyhL) for exe4.j  and [this is the .exe4j file](http://paste.ofcode.org/gjMyEKHAxaigF6xVATkVcV) associated with it.

Comment: Also, there are no errors at all, neither creating the .exe file and nor when executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say, I don't know exe4j.

What I see is, that you use `exe4jc.exe` with jars from `${lib}` but you don't reference to `${dist}/${ant.project.name}.jar`. So it seems your code that is build  won't get into the executable. That is the reason the server cannot find it (404).

```
    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the <Project>.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>

    <!-- Copy MY program into lib to get packed by exe4jc -->
    <copy file="${dist}/${ant.project.name}.jar" todir="${lib}"/>

    <!-- Create an exe -->
    <apply executable="c:\Program Files\exe4j\bin\exe4jc.exe" failonerror="true">
      <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <patternset>
          <include name="${ant.project.name}.exe4j"/>
        </patternset>
      </fileset>
    </apply>
```

Comment: It calls to `<include name="${ant.project.name}64.exe4j"/>` which includes the `Leaves64.exe4j` file I also linked in my question, which then uses `<executable name="Leaves64"...` to set the name of the exe and so on. I don't know much of `exe4j` either, but the exe is being created with no errors and runs ok until i ask for the restful API. When it doesn't crash, but it just throws the 404.

Comment: Add tried it by adding your line under `Copy my program...` same result. No improvement.

Comment: I see. Do you get any message when set `failOnError="true"` ? I still think your Leaves.jar don't get into the exe.

Comment: I tried that already. Nop, no errors. Could it be related with the ["Run as a standalone Java application" here](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/editions/jse/#run-as-a-standalone-java-application)?

Comment: Yep ok, solved. I changed [this code](http://paste.ofcode.org/UAEL4zgUxHGZU7iNZgrYcU) I was using, for [this other one](http://paste.ofcode.org/xtssBi6s9XXNei3vZNZqHp).